# backspace and delete characters not working when a textbox is validated for duplicate source code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, server-side

I have the following javascript function to validate the usercode value entered in the textbox,i am not allowing them to allow duplicate characters like AABC , BBCF.... etc, but the problem is after entering some characters its not allowing to delete the entered characters.

```
function ValidateUserCode(txtid,e) 
{

    var validateText = document.getElementById(txtid).value;
    var userText = validateText.toUpperCase();
    if (window.event)
    {
        e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode) {
        code = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e.which) {
        code = e.which;
        characterCode = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        characterCode = characterCode.toUpperCase();
    }
    if (userText.indexOf(characterCode) < 0)
     {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This my code on aspx page

```
<asp:label Text=" Code" runat="server" ID="Label"></asp:label>
 </div>
     <asp:TextBox ID="CodeTextBox" runat="server" Size="6" MaxLength="4"   Style="text-transform: uppercase;" ></asp:TextBox><br />
```

This my codebehind where i make javascript call

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             IntializeEventHandlers();

}

        private void IntializeEventHandlers()
        {

            this.CodeTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", string.Format("javascript:return ValidateUserCode('{0}',event);",this.CodeTextBox.ClientID));

        }
```

Comment: Can u post html part too ?How u bind this function to the text box control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working set of code based on what you want to do that will work in multiple browsers, and properly handles the delete/backspace/arrow keys:

```
function ValidateUserCode(txtid, e) {
    var validateText = document.getElementById(txtid).value;
    var userText = validateText.toUpperCase();
    var code = e.which;

    if (!code && ((e.charCode || e.charCode === 0) ? e.charCode : e.keyCode)) {
        code = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    }

    var characterCode = String.fromCharCode(code).toUpperCase();

    return (userText.indexOf(characterCode) < 0);
}
```

**Update**

Here's the html I used to test this:

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" onkeypress="return ValidateUserCode('mytext',event);" />
```

Make sure that the rendered html from your ASP code looks similar to this, and that the id values match.

Comment: Its allowing me to enter AASD,AABC , potentially i expect it to block when i am entering AASD

Comment: I think you have something wrong, because in a simple test page I used this on, it worked as expected. Please check the update I added to the answer about the expected html output from your ASP.